# Colorbox inframe not loading correctly - jQuery

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I'm using Colorbox for a project, and it Almost seems to work just fine. I just cannot get the "Iframe" version to work? What am I doing wrong? Can I not load a .html with iframe? I need it to be iframe, since it's loading a newsletter-form.

```
            $(document).ready(function(){

            // Display a welcome message on first visit, and set a cookie that expires in 30 days:
            if (document.cookie.indexOf('visited=false') === -1) {
            var expires = new Date();
            expires.setDate(expires.getDate()+30);
            document.cookie = "visited=true; expires="+expires.toUTCString();

            $.colorbox({iframe:true, href:"test.html"})
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a wrong combination of this piece :

```
$.colorbox({iframe:true, href:'test.html'})
```

It must look like this:

```
$.colorbox({href:'test.html', iframe:true, width:'400px',height:'250px'})
```

I really don't know why, If anyone wants to clarify it, your welcome. I only know it solved my problem.